# Wheel sieve implementation for culling operations

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, primes

The following is an excerpt taken from [Willy Good](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/01/06/pritchards-wheel-sieve/) in a comment left by him regarding culling operations and wheel sieve implementations. <kbd>As to “worse performance than the Sieve of Eratosthenes”, that isn’t necessarily true, or at least not by much: I suspect that your 
 implementation is slow because you persist in using lists to store the gaps/wheel primes and the set of candidates to be culled 
 of composites:  lists are very handy but the bane of performance (and consume memory since as well as the actual data per element,
 they also have to pointer link to the next element of 4 bytes/8 bytes for 32/64 bit systems, respectively). Of the three operations you 
 mention, 1) you don’t have to calculate gaps per culling operations if you store the wheel as gaps (preferably in an array for faster 
 access rather than a list), 2) integer multiplies aren’t expensive for a modern CPU and can be streamed to not take much more time than
 the other operations performed in parallel, and 3) integer additions are done in any case and take almost zero average time for a modern CPU.

The most practical sieves such a (C) primesieve fill the array with a precull using a pattern of the large wheel as above and then 
 do further culling using only the W4 wheel of 48 “hit” positions out of the wheel range of 210; this seems to maximize efficiency and
 trade-offs between use of memory including optimizing the use of CPU caches vs. execution speed. In order to keep the inner loop 
simple and avoid having to jump by gaps, the ‘hit” modulos are often separated out so that the innermost loops can do simple 
addition offsets for their culling (jumping by even numbers of wheels), with separate innermost loops running for each modulo 
 for each base prime. This can be done in any language, including Scheme.</kbd>

Provided this information, I have three uncertainties as to the nature of this algorithm that I will sum up in one question.

## How were the techniques mentioned in the post implemented in this program?

Given that this program does not have any form of precull.

```
def primes235(limit):
    yield 2; yield 3; yield 5
    if limit < 7: return
    modPrms = [7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31]
    gaps = [4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6] # 2 loops for overflow
    ndxs = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7]
    lmtbf = (limit + 23) // 30 * 8 - 1 # integral number of wheels rounded up
    lmtsqrt = (int(limit ** 0.5) - 7)
    lmtsqrt = lmtsqrt // 30 * 8 + ndxs[lmtsqrt % 30] # round down on the wheel
    buf = [True] * (lmtbf + 1)
    for i in xrange(lmtsqrt + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            ci = i & 7; p = 30 * (i >> 3) + modPrms[ci]
            s = p * p - 7; p8 = p << 3
            for j in range(8):
                c = s // 30 * 8 + ndxs[s % 30]
                buf[c::p8] = [False] * ((lmtbf - c) // p8 + 1)
                s += p * gaps[ci]; ci += 1
    for i in xrange(lmtbf - 6 + (ndxs[(limit - 7) % 30])): # adjust for extras
        if buf[i]: yield (30 * (i >> 3) + modPrms[i & 7])
```

To figure out how the program worked, I converted the program to python 3 and debugged it to see every process, yet some of the processes in the program just did not make sense to me, specifically ndxs and division by 30 implementation. What can be understood, however, is that there are exactly 30 elements corresponding to 30 in Mk(product of primes).

---

Update: Nxds =

```
[item for sublist in [[i]*gaps[i] for i in range(len("name of prime list"))]
            for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Try pinging the user [GordonBGood](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A549617+primes+cull) here on SO.

Comment: I spend countless hours yesterday looking at the algorithm. I believe I have figured some bits of it out, I will share them here for posterity. 23 comes from the fact that 30 - 7 = 23 and the sieve starts from position 7. The number 8 is how many numbers are left whenever the multiples of  2 3 and 5 respectively, are taken out from an interval of 30(possible primes). ndxs is used to give the next possible prime and the value that is retrieved from nxds is the total number of possible primes starting from any value 30k + 7 until the interval of 30 is finished. Minus 1 was used to get rid of 1.

Comment: I can not seem to figure out how the last portion works, specifically the mechanisms used with p8. All I have been able to infer is that the loop at the end goes through all the gaps for a specific prime and calculates a multiple as a function of p8.

Comment: @WillNess, I do not believe SO has any functionality to ping someone who is not already directly involved in a question.

Comment: If you @ someone, they get pinged.

Comment: Well then does this [forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354768/is-it-ok-to-ping-a-user-we-think-can-help#:~:text=You%20cannot%20ping%20arbitrary%20people,work%20around%20this%20intentional%20limitation.) on Meta not apply anymore?@TimRoberts

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit enough. you just need to go under any of the entries where they were participating   and leave the @ comment there asking them for help here. If you'll click  The link that I have provided you will Find That list Of such entries .

Comment: @KevinPerez I do think that  meta entry doesn't apply,  but I'm frequently at odds with the prevailing meta opinions. You just apologize for the intrusion and ask them whether they might be interested in  this question. Of course, do it only once.